# How do I set this div to be the minimum possible width to display its floating contents?

Tags: css, html

### Problem

I have "boxes" that float left so that I can display them in a line until they need to wrap. This works well, but my coloured background doesn't shrink to the minimum, it expands to the maximum.

### JSFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/RLRh6/

(Expand and shrink the *Result* section to see the effect)

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="boxes">
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
    background: #fcc;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 300px;
}

.boxes {
    background: #cfc;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.box {
    border: 1px dashed blue;
    width: 70px;
    height: 50px;
    float: left;
    margin: 2px;
}
```

### What I Get

Note the extra green colour, right of the boxes:

**Example 1**

[image: Example 1]

**Example 2**

[image: Example 2]

### What I Want

**Example 1**

[image: Example 1]

**Example 2**

[image: Example 2]

### Question

Is it possible to have the green-background div ("**.boxes**") shrink to the minimum possible size to display the boxes without Javascript? *You should be able to shrink and expand the div freely and not see any green to the right of the boxes*.

Comment: I think it's not possible doing is this way...

Comment: Are these widths and max-width going to be fixed, or are you looking for a universal solution? If the former, you could try using media queries and fix the width of `.boxes` depending on how many columns will fit, see: http://jsfiddle.net/RLRh6/8/ However I couldn't find a universal solution that would "shrink-wrap" any number of elements when max-width and/or width of boxes are unknown.

Comment: hello, when you say 'shrink' , do you mean into space avalaible just on rezize window or else ? there no context here , just a plain test page, what about in a real project ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Working DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/RLRh6/56/

If you want to achieve this only with html, css, should use media queries.

## CSS

```
.container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    min-width: 76px;
    max-width: 228px;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 76px) {
  .boxes {
      float:left;
      background: #cfc;
      width: 76px;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 152px) {
  .boxes {
      float:left;
      background: #cfc;
      width: 152px;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 228px) {
  .boxes {
      float:left;
      background: #cfc;
      width: 228px;
  }
}
.boxes {
    float:left;
    background: #cfc;
}

.box {
    border: 1px dashed blue;
    width: 70px;
    height: 50px;
    float: left;
    margin: 2px;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Remove the `min-width` from the `.container` and add `display:inline-block;`

also if you want to center the `.container` then wrap the `.container` with a `div` and apply `text-align:center` to it.

```
.container {
    background: #fcc;
    margin: 0 auto;
   display:inline-block;
}
```

[**jsFiddle Link**](http://jsfiddle.net/RLRh6/61/)

Comment: I don't see any difference.

Answer (score 2):

your container will wrap if there's a clear 'break to next line'.

Here is a pen to see different test, just set via CSS how many per line.

3.2.1 is that what you want ?

http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/gHwjz
[image]

```
.container {
    background: #fcc;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width:300px;
    }
.container.table {
  display:table;
}
.boxes {
    background: #cfc;
    display:inline-block ;/* or float */
    vertical-align:top;
}
.box {
    border: 1px dashed blue ;
    width: 70px;
    height: 50px;
    float:left;
    margin: 2px;
}

/* ====== test */
.container {clear:left;margin:1em auto;}
.container.inline-block {
  display:inline-block;
}
.container.table {
  display:table;
}
.container.float {
 float:right
}
section {
  width:450px; 
  margin:auto;
  padding:0.5em 1.5em;
  background:#ddd;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.container:before { /* see classes */
  content:attr(class);
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  margin-top:-1.2em;
}

/* wrap to next-line */
.float .box:nth-child(1n) {
clear:left;
}
.inline-block .box:nth-child(4n) {
clear:left;
}
.table .box:nth-child(odd) {
clear:left;
}
```

Comment: +1 because I feel like this is useful for learning and contributes to the discussion.

Answer (score 0):

I have done little bit changes in your css, check the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RLRh6/7/) link here if it works for you.

Followings are the css chagnes:

```
.container {
    background: #fcc;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 300px;
}

.boxes {
    background: #cfc;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding:2px;
}

.box {
    border: 1px dashed blue;
    width: 70px;
    height: 50px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 2px 2px 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't see any difference. When I shrink & expand the div, the boxes still often have extra green colour to the right. Tested in Chrome and Firefox.