# minimize rows after wrapping floated elements, but also minimize width

Tags: javascript, html, css, layout, css-float

I have a "toolbar", which has an arbitrary number of floated inline-block elements, of unknown arbitrary widths.  As the browser window gets narrower, at some point these floated elements are going to wrap down.  That's great, but what I really want is to minimize width and height when that happens.

So, before wrapping everything looks like this:

```
=======================
| XXXX XXXX XX XXXXXX |
=======================
```

And after wrapping, it looks like this:

```
================
| XXXX XXXX XX |
| XXXXXX       |
================
```

However, what I really want is for it to minimize the wasted space.  If it has to use 2 lines, I want it to wrap more elements so they fit better, like this:

```
=============
| XXXX XXXX |
| XX XXXXXX |
=============
```

1) Can this possibly be done with just CSS?

2) If not, has anyone solved this with JavaScript already?

Comment: this question seems very similar to this one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16891138/how-do-i-set-this-div-to-be-the-minimum-possible-width-to-display-its-floating-c/16952879#16952879

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, this can be done with **CSS only**.
With **Medias Queries**, you can make a wrapper X dimensions when the browser is between X and X size.

*For example:*

```
#toolbar {
  position: relative;  
  width: 100%;
}

#toolbar .wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 200px) and (max-width: 640px) {
  #container {
    width: 600px;
  }
}
```

This way, with `margin: 0 auto;` the content of your tool bar always stay centered and when it should wrap on 2 lines, you force the with to what will make it fitt perfect in 2 lines.
Hope this help.

For more information:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2FMedia_queries

Comment: This is interesting, however I don't know the widths or the orderings of the contained elements.

Comment: I guess only javascript can help to find out total width of elements and where to break the line.

Answer (score 0):

It is easily implemented with pure CSS.

1. Use a media query to wrap styles that will by applied only when the window is small enough.
2. Apply `clear: left;` to the third element. This will drop it to the next line, yay!

```css
@media (max-width: 400px) {
  #third-element {
    clear: left; }}
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/ihusom/1/edit

The container would still be page-wide. To make the container occupy minimal width possible, apply `display: inline-block;` to it.

PS You might also want to do `.container:after { clear: both; }` so that the container wrapping the floats would not collapse.

Comment: Same comment as above.  I don't know the widths or the orderings of the contained elements.

Comment: Then you can't do anything about it.

Comment: Consider writing a custom JavaScript that would measure the widths of all elements, analyze them to find the best line wrap point and apply the `clear: left;` accordingly.

Comment: Yeah -- that's where I was heading, but was hoping to avoid that.  If all else fails, that'll be my solution.